# Adding `__getattr__` method to an existing object instance

Tags: python

I would like this to work:

```py
import types

def new_getattr(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return 2

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = A()
a.__getattr__ = types.MethodType(new_getattr, a)
print(a.anything)
```

Right now, it throws `AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'anything'`.

I tried different solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance) and they work, but not for `__getattr__`.

If I do `print(a.__getattr__('anything'))`, it actually prints `2`; the problem is that my `__getattr__` method is not called automatically when I do `a.anything`.

---

As a side note, in my actual implementation, I cannot modify the definition of the class `A`, nor can I type its name and do something like `A.__getattr__ = ...` (which would work) because I need this to be generic and independent of the class name.

**Edit: I ended up doing it like this:**

`a.__class__.__getattr__ = new_getattr`.

Comment: Can't you do `a.__getattr__ = types.MethodType(new_getattr, a.__class__)`?

Comment: @grooveplex I just thought about it! Even something like `a.__class__.__getattr__ = types.MethodType(new_getattr, a)` may work.

Comment: Awesome! Mind if I post that as an answer? :)

Comment: @grooveplex Go ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not - `__dunder__` names are resolved on the type, not per-instance. Custom `__getattr__` will need to be defined directly on `A`.

See [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) section of the datamodel documentation, specifically:

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

*Note:* if you only have a reference to an instance, not the class, it is still possible to monkeypatch the type by assigning a method onto the object returned by `type(a)`.  Be warned that this will affect all existing instances, not just the `a` instance.